# Erro ao inserir dado em tabela

Tags: java, mysql

Abrindo Conexão:

```
private static final String USUARIO = "root";
private static final String SENHA = "123456";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/escolabd";
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

public static Connection abrir() throws Exception
{   
    Class.forName(DRIVER);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);

    return conn;
}

public Main()
{
    try {
        abrir();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Codigo:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO 303(Id, Aula) VALUES(?,?)";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, "0");
        stmt.setString(2, "Portugues");

        stmt.execute(); //linha 464
        stmt.close();           

    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Erro:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '303(Id, Aula) VALUES('0','Portugues')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at Default.Main.adicionar(Main.java:464)
at Default.Main$2.actionPerformed(Main.java:413)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Na linha 413 eu apenas chamo o método.

Comment: Onde vc está abrindo a conexão?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Editei agora, coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Qual sua StackTrace completa?

Comment: E só pra testar, troque o `stmt.execute()` por `stmt.executeUpdate()`

Comment: Mudei para `stmt.executeUpdate()` e continuou dando erro, coloquei o erro completo na pergunta.

Comment: Bem, o problema está na sua Query. Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Seu campo `Id` provavelmente é do tipo `int` na sua tabela. Se for, você não deve usar `stmt.setString(1, "0");` e sim, `stmt.setInt(1, 0);`

Comment: @LucasCarezia Tente mudar o nome da sua tabela, quando vc está tentando fazer o insert ele reconhece o nome da sua tabela (303) como um inteiro

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Sim, ele muda ro nome funciono, vlw.

Comment: @DiegoF Eu cometi esse erro, vlw pela dica :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema está no nome de sua tabela. Repare que está colocando um valor inteiro como nome. Se você tentar executar a `query` diretamente em um `SGBD` poderá vem a mensagem de erro com mais detalhes.

Tente trocar o nome de sua tabela de `303` para `tbl_303`, refatore seu código e faça um teste.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, o nome de uma tabela pode iniciar com números, mas não somente números. Tente mudar o nome da sua tabela, uma dica é que sempre que sua tabela tiver caracteres especiais ou é uma palavra reservada, coloque o nome da mesma entre as crases, por exemplo: `select`.